# List of servers to check for SSH availability

Tags: ssh, shell-script

I have a list of IP address that I need to SSH to and log if I could get to them. I would use a Ping script, but DNS might have already reassigned the address. I do not care about the ones I can't get to. If the SSH works I need to log that IP address, I shouldn't have to worry about passwords or keys because I don't want to log in to the box's. I just want to see if I can SSH to them. So far i have:

```
touch logfile_$(date "+%Y%m%d%T")
IP_FILE="path/to/ip_address.txt"
LOGFILE="path/to/logfile_$(date "+%Y%m%d%T")"


if [[ ! -f ${IP_FILE} ]]; then
   echo "Cannot find IP address!"
   exit 1
fi

for IP_ADDRESS in `cat $IP_FILE` ; do

    ssh $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

I am still new to scripting and any help would be great. I have looked at "How to check if I can log in to server via ssh?" posted by LanceBaynes but its not really what I need.

I can't install anything on this boxes. Or I would have downloaded a nice scanner. Like Netcat or Nmap both of which are great options.

Comment: What's the reason for you not being able to install anything on the server you're testing the connections from??

Comment: company policy. I could put in the paper work but that would take months.

Comment: Seriously? You have a policy that precludes administrators from installing whatever software they happen to need? No offense, but what kind of mindblowingly idiotic corporate entity do you have the misfortune to work for?

Comment: ya it really sucks. I cant tell you were I work for I am sorry.

Comment: @terdon - if you work with systems that deal with PCI compliance this isn't that unusual! He probably works for a place that gives him a pay check, and there are very good reasons for limiting exposure in this manner. Careful what you assume!

Comment: @slm fair enough I guess, I just have an allergy to idiotic bureaucracy and this seemed like an example of it.

Comment: I'm still confused, for example, couldn't you just run this check from your own workstation, perhaps with Cygwin installed?  Or do you have to run it from a server on which you can't install anything at all?  Can you install software on your own PC, at the office, because nmap runs on lots of operating systems.  Are you root on the server you're checking from or are you just a regular user?

Comment: @terdon - I agree, it can feel that way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Method #1: ssh-keyscan

One method would be to use the command `ssh-keyscan` to see if a ssh daemon is up and functioning.

Just loop through the IP addresses and `ssh-keyscan <ip> | grep -v ...` each server. If the server is there, the status returned by running the `ssh-keyscan ... | grep -v ...` command will be a 0, anything else (1 or higher) means there isn't a server there.

#### Example

```
$ for IP_ADDRESS in `cat $IP_FILE` ; do
    ssh-keyscan $IP_ADDRESS 2>&1 | grep -v "^$" > /dev/null
    [ $? == 0 ] && echo $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
  done
```

Just to break this down a little bit more so it's crystal clear what's going on, the `ssh-keyscan $IP_ADDRESS 2>&1` will run, any output returned (both `stderr` & `stdout` is merged together). All this output is then piped to the `grep -v "^$"` which will return a 0 for lines that return output (ssh servers running) and a 1 for servers that don't (the `"^$"` is a blank line).

**Quick tangent on loops (for vs. while & how they parse)**

The looping mechanism above (for loop) works because the file only contains a string of characters of which none are a space and that each "string" is terminated by a new line character. By default a space is the special separation character that's used to designate to the for loop how to parse the arguments being passed to it. This character is defined by the variable `$IFS` and can be overridden so that it's the new line character (`IFS='^M'`) for example.

You can make this a little more efficient by replacing the `cat $IP_FILE` with `$( < $IP_FILE )`. For example:

```
$ for IP_ADDRESS in $( < $IP_FILE ) ; do
    ssh-keyscan $IP_ADDRESS 2>&1 | grep -v "^$" > /dev/null
    [ $? == 0 ] && echo $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
  done
```

If the lines in the file `$IP_FILE` included spaces you could either override the `$IFS` as discussed a moment ago so that it was set to `^M` or a while loop could be used instead, i.e. (`while read -ra line ; do ... ; done < $IP_FILE`).

```
$ while read -ra IP_ADDRESS ; do
    ssh-keyscan $IP_ADDRESS 2>&1 | grep -v "^$" > /dev/null
    [ $? == 0 ] && echo $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
  done < $IP_FILE
```

#### Your example

```
touch logfile_$(date "+%Y%m%d%T")
IP_FILE="ip.txt"
LOGFILE="logfile_$(date "+%Y%m%d%T")"


if [[ ! -f ${IP_FILE} ]]; then
 echo "Cannot find IP address!"
 exit 1
fi

for IP_ADDRESS in `cat $IP_FILE` ; do
  #ssh $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
  ssh-keyscan $IP_ADDRESS 2>&1 | grep -v "^$" > /dev/null
  [ $? == 0 ] && echo $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
done
```

#### Method #2: nmap

You can also do something with the tool `nmap`.

```
$ nmap -A -iL ip.txt -p T:22
```

This will go through the file, `ip.txt` which can contain hostnames and IP addresses and will scan each one's TCP port # 22, returning results similar to the following:

```
Nmap scan report for somehost.somedom.local (192.168.1.200)
Host is up (0.012s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 4.3 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh-hostkey: 1024 2e:32:85:a2:56:23:01:f1:c2:8f:df:aa:83:7a:1e:ad (DSA)
|_2048 f6:a1:23:1d:aa:44:4a:ce:b4:d3:f4:fe:e1:00:47:b7 (RSA)
```

#### References

- [Nmap Network Probing Cheatsheet](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188065/Nmap-Network-Probing-Cheatsheet)
- [Top 30 Nmap Command Examples For Sys/Network Admins](http://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/)

Comment: While running this I get a [: missing `]' error on [ $? == 0] && echo $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 . any ideas?

Comment: ok give me one min. Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: Why are you using `for` and `cat` instead of `while` and `<`?

Comment: Ok so when I run it i am not receiving out put even though the ips I have in the file (all but one) are valid servers that I can ssh into.

Comment: @terdon - dunno, I always use for loops - no technical reason.

Comment: @terdon - what does everyone have against for loops? 8-) On a serious note, I find them easier to explain and understand when you're new to all this. A while loop is a much more subtle thing to grok.

Comment: How would you personally wright this using a for loop? Because i had thought about a for loop at first. if that's a better option i will just go back to that.

Comment: @user40637 - is that directed to me or terdon? I always use for loops, it's a personal preference. Some will tell you that it's less efficient but for the little bit of processing we're talking about here it's a bunk argument.

Comment: @slm - I am sorry I was talking to slm my bad, I will pick up your habit for putting a @ at the start of my posts

Comment: @user40637 - the way you approached the script is exactly how I would do it. The while loop is an alternative way to do it but how you have it is perfectly fine. There's multiple ways to do things in Unix. Using for loops is like not using contractions in English, "I am" instead of "I'm".

Comment: @ slm- how would you word this part ssh $IP_ADDRESS >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 to only tell me if its active or not.

Comment: @slm I have nothing against them unless my input strings can contain spaces or weird chars. I have just read enough of your answers to know you are way more knowledgeable than I and thought there was an obscure technical reason rather than simple preference.

Comment: @user40637 - Outside of what terdon's provided you with his method I'm not aware of any way to do this with just a basic `ssh` command. All the ways I've seen it done use another tool such as `nc` or `nmap` or a hack such as terdon's doing where he's actually making the connection and running a bogus command "echo ''" on each server. This is exactly why I was trying to steer you towards the `ssh-keyscan` method.

Comment: @slm - Ok thank you (both) for your help I will take what I learned and make a usable script with it. When I get done I will make sure to post it here for others to see.

Comment: @terdon - I've read enough of your answers to know that we know equally as much 8-). I'm hack as others, and use for loops for "style points" 8-).

Comment: @user40637 - good idea. Also change your username from user40637 to something more fitting and don't be a stranger. Everyone is here to help.

Comment: @slm we can avoid `cat filename` just using `$(< $IP_FILE )`

Comment: @RahulPatil - that would work here but doesn't parse the file a line at a time, it's parsing it splitting it on each atom in the file which isn't what I was shooting for here. For ex: `for i in $( < a );do echo "$i";done` would parse a file as `"column1"\n"column2"\n"....`

Comment: @slm I never face such issue with that..

Comment: @RahulPatil - see this example for what I'm talking about: http://pastebin.com/E1JXF5Wh

Comment: @slm hmm but I checked with cat , it's doing the same.

Comment: @RahulPatil - yes you're correct, I now realize I was overriding the `IFS='^M'` and neglecting to mention it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @slm you are my master...

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the netcat utility (binary executable is called `nc`). It can perform various network tests, among which a connection-only test to TCP port 22 would also work. If you're using the older netcat utility the command is:

`nc -vz [ip.or.hostname] 22 -w [desired.timeout.value.in.seconds]`

I believe the updated version gets rid of the `-z` option by default.

For example:

```
[jadavis6@cmsoracle ~]$ nc -vz wfwhite.xxx.edu 22 -w 5
nc: connect to wfwhite.xxx.edu port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
[jadavis6@cmsoracle ~]$ echo $?
1
[jadavis6@cmsoracle ~]$ nc -vz ditirlns01.xxx.edu 22 -w 5
Connection to ditirlns01.xxx.edu 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
[jadavis6@cmsoracle ~]$ echo $?
0
[jadavis6@cmsoracle ~]$
```

Comment: Nice solution, BTW!

Comment: That is a GREAT solution but I cant use Netcat on this boxes.

Answer (score 4):

Someone mentioned netcat, but I'm going to recommend nmap as it is a one of command to do what you want.

```
nmap -iL path/to/ip_address.txt -p 22
```

This will give you all the info you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't install anything, you should be able to do something like this (adapted from [here](http://www.standalone-sysadmin.com/blog/2011/03/guaranteeing-scripts-dont-get-hung-on-remote-ssh/)):

```
$ for ip in `cat ips.txt`; do 
    ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey foobar@$ip "echo ''" 2>&1 | 
    grep denied >/dev/null && echo "$ip has SSH"; 
  done < ips.txt
```

The trick here is `PreferredAuthentications`. This tells `ssh` to attempt to connect using the key information stored in `~/.ssh`. As long as the user `foobar` does not have access to the remote system (change it to whatever random name you want), the connection will fail with a "Permission denied" error. This means that the `grep denied` will be successful and therefore the `echo` command will be run. `&&` means run the next command if the previous one (here, the `grep`) was successful.

If you run this scriptlet on a file containing the IPs, it will print out only those servers with a running ssh service.

Comment: You might want to add a command to the `ssh` invocation, otherwise it will try to spawn a terminal session with each server. In the linked example they were doing that by passing `$COMMAND` to the `ssh` invocation.

Comment: As Joel said, if you do a straight `ssh` you're opening the connection which is why I was trying to avoid it, by using `ssh-keyscan` or something else such as `nc` or `nmap`.

Comment: @JoelDavis yes, I was assuming the OP would not have access to simplify the solution. Answer modified.

Comment: @terdon - getting rid of the connection is a bit of pain, good idea there. If he can't `ssh` to the system without a public key, this won't work though, right?

Comment: @slm I have modified this solution a bit by using a non existent user name, that way you should always get an "Access denied" error from servers that have ssh set up.